# Importing Contracts

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

Trying to import contracts from on-premise to online host.  I tweaked the SDK solution "dataimport" however I'm having trouble with the required lookup attribute `CustomerIdName`.  It gives

> error 2147220654 "A duplicate lookup reference was found"

Another mapping to lookup attribute `contracttemplateid` works just fine.  I think it has something to do with the fact this can map either to `account` or `contact` entity.  Source file (just 1 record row) and code below.  This is 1 column mapping based on the `ImportWithCreate` class included with the sdk solution.

```
title,activeon,allotmenttypecode,expireson,billingstarton,billingendon,
new_companyorindividual,CustomerIdName, Acme Consulting Company,
5/1/2000,1,1/23/2002,5/1/2000,1/23/2002,0,USF Admin
```

```
#region Column Eight Mappings
            // Create a column mapping for a 'lookup' type field.
            ColumnMapping colMapping8 = new ColumnMapping()
            {
                // Set source properties.
                SourceAttributeName = "CustomerIdName",
                SourceEntityName = "Contract_1",

                // Set target properties.
                TargetAttributeName = "customerid",
                TargetEntityName = Contract.EntityLogicalName,

                // Relate this column mapping with the data map.
                ImportMapId =
                    new EntityReference(ImportMap.EntityLogicalName, importMapId),

                // Force this column to be processed.
                ProcessCode =
                    new OptionSetValue((int)ColumnMappingProcessCode.Process),
            };

            // Create the mapping.
            Guid colMappingId8 = _serviceProxy.Create(colMapping8);

            // Because we created a column mapping of type lookup, we need to specify lookup details in a lookupmapping.
            // One lookupmapping will be for the parent account, and the other for the current record.
            // This lookupmapping is important because without it the current record
            // cannot be used as the parent of another record.

            // Create a lookup mapping to the parent account.  
            LookUpMapping parentLookupMapping8 = new LookUpMapping()
            {
                // Relate this mapping with its parent column mapping.
                ColumnMappingId =
                    new EntityReference(ColumnMapping.EntityLogicalName, colMappingId8),

                // Force this column to be processed.
                ProcessCode =
                    new OptionSetValue((int)LookUpMappingProcessCode.Process),

                // Set the lookup for an account entity by its name attribute.
                LookUpEntityName = Account.EntityLogicalName,
                //LookUpEntityName = Contact.EntityLogicalName,
                LookUpAttributeName = "name",
                LookUpSourceCode =
                    new OptionSetValue((int)LookUpMappingLookUpSourceCode.System)
            };

            // Create the lookup mapping.
            Guid parentLookupMappingId8 = _serviceProxy.Create(parentLookupMapping8);

            // Create a lookup on the current record's "src_name" so that this record can
            // be used as the parent account for another record being imported.
            // Without this lookup, no record using this account as its parent will be imported.
            LookUpMapping currentLookUpMapping8 = new LookUpMapping()
            {
                // Relate this lookup with its parent column mapping.
                ColumnMappingId =
                    new EntityReference(ColumnMapping.EntityLogicalName, colMappingId8),

                // Force this column to be processed.
                ProcessCode =
                    new OptionSetValue((int)LookUpMappingProcessCode.Process),

                // Set the lookup for the current record by its src_name attribute.
                LookUpAttributeName = "CustomerIdName",
                LookUpEntityName = "Contract_1",
                LookUpSourceCode =
                    new OptionSetValue((int)LookUpMappingLookUpSourceCode.Source)
            };

            // Create the lookup mapping
            Guid currentLookupMappingId8 = _serviceProxy.Create(currentLookUpMapping8);
            #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

I hav'nt scripted my own data import like that before, but I have seen that error.

I suspect this might be because you have two contacts/accounts with the name "USF Admin".

Its trying to find a unique record for the lookup field, and if there is a duplicate it doesnt know which to set.

You could also try performing the data import manually using the standard CRM data import tools, this might help you to narrow down if theres a problem in the code or the data.

Answer (score 0):

No duplicates. Microsoft support was able to resolve by commenting out the block of code for the LookUpMapping for that particular one.

//LookUpMapping currentLookUpMapping = new LookUpMapping()